# How to Check if a User Input is More than One Letter and Have it Display Correctly in C++

Tags: c++, validation, character, user-input, letter

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent my code from continuing if a user has entered more than 1 character. I tried looking through the forums but I couldn't find the right answers I was looking for.

Basically I'm trying to validate if the user has entered more than 1 character and prompt them to try again if they have.

The user input will also be printed out, and for some reason it prints as a number. Here is a sample of my current code:

```
        //gets student's last initial. Checks if the input is a 1 letter character
        //has a response if it is not
        bool lastEntry = false;
        while (lastEntry != true){
            cout << "Please enter the initial of your last name: " << endl;
            cin >> lastInitial;

            if (isalpha(lastInitial)) {
                cout << "Last initial has been logged." << endl;
                lastEntry = true;
            } 
            else {
                cout << "That is an invalid choice. Please enter a letter: " << endl;
                cin >> lastInitial;
            }//end if
        }//end while loop

        //prints summary of student's input and displays output
        cout << "Your name initials are: " << toupper(firstInitial) << toupper(lastInitial) << endl;
        cout << "Once swapped, your name initials will be: " << toupper(lastInitial) << toupper(firstInitial) << endl;
    }//end Choice A option
```

When I test it, the numerical validation works, but when I type more than 1 character for my input, it will finish my code. This is what it shows:

[image]

Notes:
firstInitial and lastInitial are declared in the beginning of my code as:

```
char firstInitial;
char lastInitial;
```

I currently have #include iostream and #include ctype.h and I use //using namespace std;// to remove the usage of std:: in my code. If this has specifically been asked, I apologize; and please send me a link to the answer! If my code could be more efficient, please let me know that as well! Thank you.

Comment: Am I right that these are actually two questions?: 1.) How to prevent input of more than one letter? 2.) Why the output of integer? As Roya gave the answer for 2.), I believe it's not that simple to prevent your 1st issue with std lib. I/O. What I would recommend: Read a `std::string` with `std::getline()` so that length of input doesn't hurt. Afterwards you can evaluate length. If it's 0 => ERROR! Repeat again. If it's 1 => just take the front of string as character. Otherwise (> 1), you may do as well and give additionally a WARNING! Please, consider carefully what has been requested.

Comment: Hi Scheff, yes two questions. Is it still possible to write the std:: in conjunction with the using namespace std;? I'm still only a few weeks into learning C++ so little things like that would be good for me to know for the future in case I need to problem solve again. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, `using namespace std` can be mixed with explicit scoping `std::`: [**Life Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b30347c219fd191e). However, I recommend to drop the `using namespace std;` completely, at least on global scope. While it seems convenient, it causes that everything of `namespace std` is "pulled" into global namespace which can have unexpected or unnoticed and unintended side effects.

Answer (score 1):

[`toupper`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/toupper) returns an integer and you need to convert it to a char when printing. Like this :

```
static_cast<char>(toupper(lastInitial))
```

Comment: May be, it's worth to mention that std. lib. has a variety of overloaded stream `operator<<`s where those for integral types output the value (decimal or whatever is specified) except for `char` and `unsigned char` (and hence `int8_t` and `uint8_t` as well) which prints instead the character. (using value e.g. as ASCII value)

Comment: Hi Roya, thank you for this I used these in my program and it outputs correctly now!